# If condition in Integer Programming

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, gurobi, integer-programming

I am solving an integer programming problem with the condition

if a=0 then b=0 else b=1

where a is integer while b is binary

I looked on previous question similar to this but could not find solution.
please help to define constraint equation in integer programming for above conditions.

Comment: What types are they?

Comment: a is integer while b is binary

Answer (score 1):

The first constraint is easy: a=0 ⇒ b=0 can be written as a ≥ b. The second constraint (a ≥ 1 ⇒ b=1) is more complicated. If a ≤ M where M is relatively small, then you can write this as M ⋅ b ≥ a. Otherwise, you will need to use a solver feature called [indicator constraints](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_addgenconstrindic.html).

Comment: thanks for reply , constraint a ≥ b does not hold true if a is negative integer

Comment: Typically, there are no negative integers in Integer Programming. A lower bound of zero is assumed if not stated otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use these two constraints:

```
a<=bM
b<=aM
```

where M is a big number (M>a). When a=0, the 1st constraint is redundant, 2nd one gonna impose b=0. If a>0 then 2nd constraint is redundant, but the 1st one gonna force the b gets the value of 1 (if M is enough big).

Comment: Since b is binary, you should simplify the second constraint to b <= a.

Comment: Greg, It was my misreading of your previous answer, I though the (dot) you put after M is a colon. Basically, I just anwsered what you already did.M is not necessary in the 2nd constraint as you mentioned.